# Prisma 2: Setting Minimum & Maximum Length of a String type

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I am creating a model using Prisma 2 and want to set a minimum and maximum length for one of the fields.  I.e., something like this:

```
model Post {
 ...
 title String @min(3) @max(240)
 ...
}
```

I just made up the above syntax.  I am wondering if something like that exists in Prisma and, if so, how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Annotation `@db.VarChar`

You can set the maximum length using the annotation `@db.VarChar`:

```
model Post {
 ...
 title String @db.VarChar(240)
 ...
}
```

There is no support for adding the minimum length as for now.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know.